# Select Text of Element, but Not of Children

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, xpath, web-scraping, screen-scraping

I found myself confronted by the following code, from which I'm trying to scrape certain information such as the text and hyperlinks:

```
<td class="value">
  #1 in Musical Instruments, Stage &amp; Studio (<a href="https://www.amazon.ca/gp/bestsellers/musical-instruments/ref=pd_dp_ts_musical-instruments_1">See top 100</a>)
  <ul class="zg_hrsr">
    <li class="zg_hrsr_item">
      <span class="zg_hrsr_rank">#1</span>
      <span class="zg_hrsr_ladder">in&nbsp;<a href="https://www.amazon.ca/gp/bestsellers/musical-instruments/16596681011/ref=pd_zg_hrsr_musical-instruments_1_1_last">Studio Headphones</a></span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</td>
```

First — and less importantly — I'm not sure why the text below, which is extracted from a [webpage](https://www.amazon.ca/Bluetooth-Wireless-Headphones-Earphones-Sweatproof/dp/B07GSZZ6JY/ref=gbps_img_s-3_4bc8_18ef6727?smid=A1NEE9870G6ZKD&pf_rd_p=f5836aee-0969-4c39-9720-4f0cacf64bc8&pf_rd_s=slot-3&pf_rd_t=701&pf_rd_i=gb_main&pf_rd_m=A3DWYIK6Y9EEQB&pf_rd_r=WTMMM0PBSA6TSW343GM1), doesn't match the text in the code or on the actual page?

```
#1 in Musical Instruments, Stage & Studio (See top 100)
#1 in Musical Instruments, Stage & Studio > Studio Recording Equipment > Headphones & In-Ear Monitors > Headphones
```

And here is the text as it is displayed on the actual [page](https://www.amazon.ca/Bluetooth-Wireless-Headphones-Earphones-Sweatproof/dp/B07GSZZ6JY/ref=gbps_img_s-3_4bc8_18ef6727?smid=A1NEE9870G6ZKD&pf_rd_p=f5836aee-0969-4c39-9720-4f0cacf64bc8&pf_rd_s=slot-3&pf_rd_t=701&pf_rd_i=gb_main&pf_rd_m=A3DWYIK6Y9EEQB&pf_rd_r=WTMMM0PBSA6TSW343GM1).

```
#1 in Musical Instruments, Stage & Studio (See top 100)
#1 in Studio Headphones
```

Here is the part of my script that extracts the text from the webpage.

```
rank_categories = ff.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="SalesRank"]/td[2]')
if len(rank_categories) > 0:
    rank_categories = rank_categories[0].text
else:
    rank_categories = ff.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="SalesRank"]').text

# rank_categories is td.value
```

Lastly — and most importantly — is there any way to extract the text of a given element while excluding or not also selecting the text of child elements?

In the example above, I'd like to be able to extract `#1 in Musical Instruments, Stage & Studio (See top 100)`, `#1`, and `in Studio Headphones` separately, to save myself the hassle of writing extremely complicated regular expressions in order to parse the information.

Is there a way to select only the text of the selected element while not also selecting the text of its children?